# How can I specify code to run on "PageLoad" in an old ASP.NET site?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pageload, page-lifecycle

I am maintaining an old site that has code like this:

```
<%
Unit = Request.QueryString.Item("Unit")
MemberNo = Request.QueryString.Item("MemberNo")
CustNo = Request.QueryString.Item("CustNo")
If Request.Form.Item("Action") = "Save" Then
. . .
%>
```

I need to run some code when the page loads. Is there something available like:

```
If Request.Form.Item("Action") = "Load" Then
```

--or:

```
If Request.Form.Item("Action") = "Init" Then
```

...or how do I do this?

### UPDATE

Where should I put that code you show? The file has a section like this:

```
<script language="VB" runat="Server">
Dim adoRS As ADODB.Recordset
. . .
</script>
```

...and another like this:

```
<%
adoCon = New ADODB.Connection
adoCon.CommandTimeout = 900
adoCon.ConnectionTimeout = 900
adoCon.Open((Session("DBAddress")))
%>
```

Is one place preferable than the other, or even exclusively the only one to use? Or is neither acceptable?

Actually, if I put the code in the first block, I will have to move the code from the second block there, too, because I need the ADODBConnection for the PageLoad code.

### UPDATE 2

Ciprian's answer said:

*If the aspx.vb page does not exist, check the first line in the .aspx file. It should look something like this:*

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default...
```

My .aspx file has this at the top:

```
<%@ Import namespace="ADODB" %>
<script language="VB" runat="Server">
. . .
```

IOW, I have no such first line as Ciprian expects I should have. The project also has no "Site.master" page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out all I needed to do was just to put it at the top of the code, like so:

```
<%
Unit = Request.QueryString.Item("Unit")
MemberNo = Request.QueryString.Item("MemberNo")
CustNo = Request.QueryString.Item("CustNo")

'determine whether this unit is a new business
currentYear = Year(Now)
SQLString = "Select NewBiz from MasterUnitsprojSales where CYear = " & currentYear & " and Unit = '" & Unit & "'"
adoRS = New ADODB.Recordset
adoRS.Open(SQLString, adoCon)
IsNewBusiness = TRUE 'default (if record not found)
If Not adoRS.EOF Then
    IsNewBusiness = adoRS.Fields.Item(0).Value <> 0 
    Response.Write("<!-- IsNewBusiness after NOT EOF assignment = " & CStr(IsNewBusiness) & "-->")
End If
adoRS.Close()

If Request.Form.Item("Action") = "Save" Then
. . .
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean on the ASPX page, as opposed to the code behind.  ASP.Net will try to find event handlers by name on the ASPX page, so this should work:

```
<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Page_Load(Byval sender as Object, Byval e As EventArgs)
        'Code Here
    End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: @NoAlias: Please see my Update

Answer (score 1):

In Web Forms, you have .aspx pages corresponding to a view. Each page has a code-behind file with a class (e.g. About.aspx has an About.aspx.vb class). The code for Page Load should go in your Page_Load method:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub
```

You can have a look at Web Forms life cycle here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

If the aspx.vb page does not exist, check the first line in the .aspx file. It should look something like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication4._Default" %>
```

Notice "CodeBehind" and "Inherits" attributes. They should point to code behind file, and name of the class, respectively. The .aspx.vb file should look like this:

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Additionally, you would need a .aspx.designer.vb file, similar to this:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated. 
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On


Partial Public Class _Default
End Class
```

Comment: No, this project has no code-behind files - no *.aspx.vb ... I take it back, there are a handful of *.aspx files that do have *.aspx.vb, after all. The file in question does not, though. How can I add one?

Comment: "View Code" and "View Markup" both take me to the *.aspx file.